# What exactly does "detach" method of ViewContainerRef Class in Angular do?

Tags: angular

Angular docs describes as:

> Use along with `insert` to move a View within the current container.

But when I use it, it seems like, the component or whatever elements attached to it disappear somewhere. I can't see it in DOM.

What does it exactly do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove = Removes the Component from the **DOM Tree** (calls the **ngOnDestroy** Lifecycle Hook).

detach = Removes the Component from the **DOM Tree** but the Component is still "alive" and can be added back to the **DOM Tree** with the **insert** Method.

Comment: So, the `ngOnInit` hook won't be called when it's inserted back?

Answer (score 0):

> ...the component or whatever elements attached to it disappear somewhere. I can't see it in DOM.

The `detach()` function removes the element in a given index (or 0 by default) from the viewContainerRef from which it was called.
So basically you can remove an element from the DOM and insert it back to without the need to rebuild the template.
You can find a good use case of this with the search directive [here](https://searchable-9tbjxw.stackblitz.io)